# 404 on Custom route for admin module

Tags: magento-1.9, router

I'm adding a new action in orders grid (it works), but the **action route** gives **404** error (route error).

I have a custom config.xml like this (app/code/local/AAAA/MassActions/etc/config.xml).

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <AAAA_MassActions>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </AAAA_MassActions>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <AAAA_MassActions before="Mage_Adminhtml">AAAA_MassActions_Adminhtml</AAAA_MassActions>
                    </modules>
                </args>
                <frontName>massactions</frontName>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Controller looks like (app/code/local/AAAA/MassActions/controllers/Adminhtml/MassActionsController.php)

```
<?php

class AAAA_MassActions_Adminhtml_MassActionsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
  public function massPaymentChange()
    {
        $method = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('method');
```

And my observer (working because is adding the mass) but the route problem probably is in this part of code (app/code/local/AAAA/MassActions/Model/Observer.php):

```
$block->addItem('massactions', array(
                'label' => 'Payment Method change',
                'url' => Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/massactions/massPaymentChange'),
                'confirm' => __('Confirm?'),
                'additional' => array(
                    'visibility' => array(
                         'name' => 'method',
                         'type' => 'select',
                         'class' => 'required-entry',
                         'label' => __('Payment Method'),
                         'values' => $methods
                    )
                )
            ));
```

IN my adminhtml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Payment Method Change</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <massactions translate="title">
                                        <title>Payment Method Change</title>
                                    </massactions>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

404 error url is in: example.com/index.php/**admin/massactions/massPaymentChange/**

Comment: I guess that's because the controller is missing in the URL: You have the route to the module and the action, but not the controller in the URL. The URL should rather be example.com/index.php/admin/massactions/massActions/massPaymentChange/

Comment: How this will works in                 'url' => Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminhtml/massactions/massActions/massPaymentChange'), ?

Comment: change `public function massPaymentChange()` into `public function massPaymentChangeAction()` and clear your cache after

Comment: thx, @AttilaNaghi, works